# How do i make the simulator open onto the same screen as xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, screen

I was wondering how to open the simulator on the same screen as Xcode. I've seen it done on the IOS bootcamp on Udemy, when simulator is opened it pops up on the same screen as Xcode as [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4lC6.jpg) does anyone know how to achieve this result?

Ive managed already to get the simulator to be in the same screen but its next to it in a different window [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmCGd.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Looking over your desired result and the screenshot labeled as undesirable, it appears that you only need to ensure the Simulator is the active element on your screen and select the `Window` menu at the top of the screen and select `Stay on Top`.

[image]